# Design Pattern: Modular Command Architecture (Workflow?)

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, workflow, speech-recognition

I've  got an app which responds to vocal commands. Examples include: `Read Headlines`, `Start Visual Srudio`. The app provides feedback via TTS.

I'dlike to expand the app to be modular. Each module should be able to:

- Extend the list of known commands
- Open UI windows (which the parent App must be aware of so it can close them on command in a standard way)
- Queue text for the TTS engine - probably with a priority flag
- Support dialogue back-and-forth - `Show a map of Bristol` might evoke a response of `Bristol USA or England?` and then listen for the specific response.

Can someone suggest an appropriate design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to design the spoken command feedback, the architecture approach is simple and established. Event-based source/listener approach with plugins which can subscribe to events and respond to them should work

For dialog system the design is more complex. Dialog management require you to have a tree-like knowledge space representation and to have a manager to track the dialog progress. It's recommended to try and read about Olympus system from CMU to become familar with the concepts and decisions used:

http://wiki.speech.cs.cmu.edu/olympus/index.php/Olympus

Bohus, Dan & Alexander I. Rudnicky (2009), "The RavenClaw dialog management framework: Architecture and systems", Computer Speech & Language

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B6WCW-4TVJ3KG-1/2/d6bfd64173650f150219cf4a43a51a66

Bohus, Dan & Alexander I. Rudnicky (2003), "RavenClaw: Dialog Management Using Hierarchical Task Decomposition and an Expectation Agenda", Eurospeech 2003

http://research.microsoft.com/~dbohus/docs/ravenclaw.ps

For more complex design with self-learning and semantic information extraction you need to head to the publications on CALO project which ended in SIRI

https://pal.sri.com/Plone/framework/Components

It's all well explained how this system responds, learns and reacts.

Comment: Those look like excellent resources, thank you. I'll get reading.